# Handle downloading app from app like appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, progress-bar, openurl

I want to handle downloading application from another application that appstore makes.
We use enterprise licence and publish lots of applications from our server One main application and others sub. People download new applications or updates from main application like below.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest& url=http://example.com/2ndapp.plist"];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

I uploaded sample screen because of reputation point to http://i40.tinypic.com/2m4prao.png

While downloading I want to show progress bar in main application. In android we can do this. Can we handle this in IOS.

Thanks.

Comment: As long as your server response header tells the client about the file size. You can create progress bar. You have to make sure that when the download button clicked you have to know the total size of the data is coming.

Comment: client not downloading text file or data. When hit download install newapp.ipa to device. So I cannot sure about if it installed or not(can be stop,corrupt internet connection). If [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url] returns true I know that app is installed.@doNotCheckMyBlog